# Null-able DatePicker in windows universal apps

Tags: xaml, datepicker, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

In my windows universal app for tablet, I am working with datepicker to which current date is set automatically. But how do I make it blank or nullable. i have got two date pickers ValidFrom and ValidUntil. ValidFrom datepicker is fine as it is mandatory entry. But ValidUntil DatePicker is not mandatory but the user can still see the current date on it which I want to make it blank.

Is there any way I can use TextBox/TextBlock for UI and onClick/onTouch populate the datePicker? I tried to have a look but could not find any relevant samples.

datePicker is different in both windows phone and tablet apps. My application is an universal for tablets.

Could you suggest what is the best way to make the ValidUntil datepicker nullable? or textBox which populates the datePicker.

Another question is even if i populate the datePicker onClick/onTouch of textBox will it populate as a calender or just a single row with user selecting date/month/year separately?

XAML

```
<DatePicker/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For nullable DatePicker, you could try this : 
Updating the classes of `DatePicker` & `SelectedDateChangedEventArgs`  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace WinRTDatePicker
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "_DayOptions", Type = typeof(ComboBox))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "_MonthOptions", Type = typeof(ComboBox))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "_YearOptions", Type = typeof(ComboBox))]
    public sealed class DatePicker : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(DateTime?), SelectedDateChangedCallback));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DayOptionFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DayOptionFormat", typeof(string), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MonthOptionFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MonthOptionFormat", typeof(string), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public event EventHandler<SelectedDateChangedEventArgs> SelectedDateChanged; 

        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> daysInRange = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> monthsInRange = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> yearsInRange = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public DatePicker()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DatePicker);

            //SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            DayOptionFormat = "dd dddd";
            MonthOptionFormat = "MMMM";
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            monthsInRange.Clear();
            monthsInRange.Add("Month");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                DateTime monthStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i, 1);
                monthsInRange.Add(monthStart.ToString(MonthOptionFormat));
            }

            CreateBindings();
            SetSelectedDate(SelectedDate);

            DayOptions.SelectionChanged += DayOptionsOnSelectionChanged;
            MonthOptions.SelectionChanged += MonthOptionsOnSelectionChanged;
            YearOptions.SelectionChanged += YearOptionsOnSelectionChanged;
        }

        private void SetSelectedDate(DateTime? newSelectedDate)
        {
            if (DayOptions != null && MonthOptions != null && YearOptions != null)
            {
                var TempNewSelectedDate = newSelectedDate;
                if (newSelectedDate == null)
                {
                    newSelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
                }
                daysInRange.Clear();
                yearsInRange.Clear();

                daysInRange.Add("Date");
                for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(newSelectedDate.Value.Year, newSelectedDate.Value.Month); i++)
                {
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(newSelectedDate.Value.Year, newSelectedDate.Value.Month, i);
                    daysInRange.Add(date.ToString(DayOptionFormat));
                }

                int minYear = newSelectedDate.Value.Year - 10;
                int maxYear = newSelectedDate.Value.Year + 10;

                yearsInRange.Add("Year");
                for (int i = minYear; i <= maxYear; i++)
                {
                    yearsInRange.Add(i.ToString());
                }

                if (TempNewSelectedDate != null)
                {
                    DayOptions.SelectedIndex = newSelectedDate.Value.Day;
                    MonthOptions.SelectedIndex = newSelectedDate.Value.Month;
                    YearOptions.SelectedItem = newSelectedDate.Value.Year.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    DayOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    MonthOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    YearOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateBindings()
        {
            Binding dayOptionsBinding = new Binding { Source = daysInRange, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
            DayOptions.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, dayOptionsBinding);

            Binding monthOptionsBinding = new Binding { Source = monthsInRange, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
            MonthOptions.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, monthOptionsBinding);

            Binding yearOptionsBinding = new Binding { Source = yearsInRange, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
            YearOptions.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, yearOptionsBinding);
        }

        private void UpdateSelectedDateFromInputs()
        {
            if (YearOptions.SelectedIndex > 0 && MonthOptions.SelectedIndex > 0 && DayOptions.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                int year = int.Parse(YearOptions.SelectedValue.ToString());
                int month = MonthOptions.SelectedIndex;
                int day = DayOptions.SelectedIndex;

                int maxDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
                if (day > maxDaysInMonth)
                {
                    day = maxDaysInMonth;
                    DayOptions.SelectedIndex = maxDaysInMonth - 1;
                }

                if (month == 0)
                    month = 1;

                if (day == 0)
                    day = 1;

                SelectedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            }
            else if (YearOptions.SelectedIndex == 0 && MonthOptions.SelectedIndex == 0 && DayOptions.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                SelectedDate = null;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDayOptions()
        {
            if (SelectedDate != null)
            {
                int selectedDayIndex = DayOptions.SelectedIndex;
                int month = MonthOptions.SelectedIndex;

                if (month != 0)
                {
                    daysInRange.Clear();
                    daysInRange.Add("Date");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(SelectedDate.Value.Year, month); i++)
                    {
                        DateTime date = new DateTime(SelectedDate.Value.Year, month, i);
                        daysInRange.Add(date.ToString(DayOptionFormat));
                    }

                    DayOptions.SelectedIndex = selectedDayIndex;  
                }
            }
        }

        private void DayOptionsOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
        {
            UpdateSelectedDateFromInputs();
        }

        private void MonthOptionsOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
        {
            UpdateSelectedDateFromInputs();
            UpdateDayOptions();
        }

        private void YearOptionsOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
        {
            UpdateSelectedDateFromInputs();
            UpdateDayOptions();
        }

        private static void SelectedDateChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            DateTime oldValue = args.OldValue != null ? (DateTime)args.OldValue : DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime? newValue = (DateTime?)args.NewValue;

            if (newValue != oldValue)
            {
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)obj;
                datePicker.SetSelectedDate(newValue);

                if (datePicker.SelectedDateChanged != null)
                    datePicker.SelectedDateChanged(datePicker, new SelectedDateChangedEventArgs(newValue));
            }
        }

        public DateTime? SelectedDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
        }

        public string DayOptionFormat
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DayOptionFormatProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DayOptionFormatProperty, value); }
        }

        public string MonthOptionFormat
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MonthOptionFormatProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MonthOptionFormatProperty, value); }
        }

        private ComboBox DayOptions
        {
            get { return (ComboBox)GetTemplateChild("_DayOptions"); }
        }

        private ComboBox MonthOptions
        {
            get { return (ComboBox)GetTemplateChild("_MonthOptions"); }
        }

        private ComboBox YearOptions
        {
            get { return (ComboBox)GetTemplateChild("_YearOptions"); }
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace WinRTDatePicker
{
    public class SelectedDateChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly DateTime? newDate;

        public SelectedDateChangedEventArgs(DateTime? newDate)
        {
            this.newDate = newDate;
        }

        public DateTime? NewDate
        {
            get { return newDate; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see ref : [windows store app date picker null date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535604/windows-store-app-date-picker-null-date)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and the answer posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c276749d-3ac4-4489-a53e-43f97a01aeb7/uwp-set-empty-value-to-datepicker?forum=wpdevelop) was very useful.

My XAML ended up being something like the following where the Button Content is bound to the same field that the DatePickerFlyout is so that it will show the selected value:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=SomeDate, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout Date="{Binding Path=SomeDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Add in some simple styling to the button and a converter for showing the date in the button and another one for changing the DatePicker's DateTimeOffset value to a DateTime and you're done.